# This app it is not supported on this type of Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, build, compilation

I have an Xcode project which holds different versions of my game: iOS (iPhone and iPad) and OS X.

I have a different target for each device, platform. Every application works fine, on simulator, devices, etc. I even have some builds currently in the iOS AppStore.

My problem is with the OS X build, which runs just fine when launched from Xcode, but with this forbidden icon on top of the regular app icon.

[image: Icon with forbidden sign]

The problem, is when I try to export/archive this build, the exported application still has this forbidden mark. And when I launch it from the Finder, I get the following message.

```
You can’t open the application “Foo bar” because it is not supported on this type of Mac.
```

I did try to run the following command:

```
file Contents/MacOS/Foobar
```

Which outputs:

```
Contents/MacOS/Foobar: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

I would think it should run just fine on my Macbook Air, plus it runs well when launched from Xcode debug command.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had forgotten to remove this settings from my OS X Info.plist file:

```
Application requires iPhone environment --> YES
```

Thanks Michelle for the great help! The flag lead me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When launched from Xcode, the compiler uses the Debug build configuration.
When building for archive it uses Release (or Distribution or what you have selected in Scheme definition). 
In your OS X target check the Architectures and Valid Architectures flags in Build Settings, they should differ between Debug and Release (or Distribution or what you have).

Comment: Well the thing is that I've configure my scheme to use Release configuration when launched from Xcode, in order to test such differences. And it works too from Xcode in Release mode. So this is not the issue, I guess.

Comment: If your run the file command on the debug build (Products > your app > Show in Finder) what do you get?

Comment: Foobar.app/Contents/MacOS/Foobar: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

Comment: Maybe something is broken with Launch Services db: try touch Foobar.app

Comment: As a side note. When archiving the app. I still can't launch it from Finder (still forbidden icon). But if I make an "open Foobar.app/Contents/MacOS/Foobar", the app starts correctly.

Comment: Have a look at the LaunchServices db: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump. Search for Foobar, then have a look at the items flags. Try also duplicating the .app with Finder. Then, I don't have any suggestion more...

Comment: Ok, I think I can see the problem, but don't how to fix it. The build flags seem defined as an iOS app: https://gist.github.com/3981782